# How to move the body of someone I killed myself?

Tags: deus-ex

How can I move the body of someone I killed or rendered unconscious? If I activate a body, it only acts like a container. I was able to move the bodies of those that I didn't kill on my own after the first mission.

Comment: Title should be: How do I hide the body? :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually quite obvious: You have to unequip anything to move a body. I guess I just happened not to have equipped a weapon at the end of mission 1.

Comment: You also have to loot the body before it can be moved.

Comment: By default, the Backspace key is bound to the unequip action.